# A doubt in Probability essentials by Protter

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image: Please see part (v)]

Why is the first inequality valid(In part (v))? I mean I know that we can show that if $X \in L^2 \implies X \in L^1 $ by using **Holder's Inequality**.
This inequality does not make any sense to me howsoever. I would be grateful if someone could explain me why!
Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of $p_{\omega}$? Is $\Omega$ a countable space here?

Comment: $p_{\omega}=P(\{\omega\}), \omega \in \Omega$

Comment: the probability is defined on a countable space, where $p_{\omega}$ is the probability of each atom

Comment: X is an indicator function so no absolute values are necessary, yes? It's 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, at least to me, that taking the absolute values off there after the first inequality is not necessary, or maybe not even desirable. Note that $\Omega=\{\omega:|X(\omega)|<1\}\cup\{\omega:|X(\omega)|\geq 1\}$ and these sets are disjoint, so the sum is only divided to two different parts there. In more detail:

1. In the first inequality he divides the sum over those two disjoint sets. You can keep absolute values here on both sums on the right and we have an equality instead of an inequality.
2. Then he uses the estimate on $|X(\omega)|<1$ in the first sum of the second inequality by replacing $|X(\omega)|p_{\omega}$ with $p_{\omega}$, and in the second sum as $|X(\omega)|\geq 1$ then $|X(\omega)|\leq |X(\omega)|^{2}$.
3. He omitted this step but in the second inequality he finally replaces the sum over a subset of $\Omega$ by sum over the whole $\Omega$ in both sums.

Comment: But then why use an inequality, it should be an equality with the absolute value of $|X(\omega)|$?

Comment: @user3503589: There is probably a mistake in the print. What is certain is, that once you leave the absolute values you have an equality, and he is, essentially, arguing that if you drop the absolute values the estimate grows. Which seems to be false. But you can keep the absolute values and the argument goes through.

Comment: Okay and the second inequality is clear . Thank you Thomas for the swift reply

Comment: Isn't it important that X is an indicator function?

Comment: @jdods: $X$ is an indicator function in part $(v)$ and this seems to be a discontinuation of it, and rather a general statement. In either case it makes no difference, if one leaves the absolute values the argument goes through with same steps.

Comment: @jdods Those two are not related I guess

Comment: @user3503589: You're welcome.

Comment: Ok op seemed to think the inequality was part of part v. Hard to tell without more context.

Comment: What if X takes negative values? Nvm, I see. Must be a typo.